# How do you do a page curl animation without using the iPhone's built-in curlUp and curlDown animations?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I would like to animate a page flipping, like is [shown here](http://www.page-flip.com/new-demos/06-bombardier/index.html), but without using the built-in UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp and UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown animations.  Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to use curlUp and curlDown or that you are seeking another solution ?

Comment: I know how to use curlUp and Down But I'm not using.

Comment: Why not just use the built in methods? Much easier. Unless of course you're trying to learn how. In which case, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html).  I think it uses private methods, but it works.  Its a great starting point to figuring out how do do it yourself.